# Showing Legend in Wolfram Mathematica

Tags: plotting, legending

The code below displays a histogram of the data and superimposes plots of five Weibull distributions for comparison. I have assigned colors to each Weibull curve in the distribution plots.

How can I include a legend with labels for each Weibull curve? Just to clarify, I don't really care what name is assigned to each curve shown in the legend.

```
data =
 {0, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1,
  0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 
  0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 
  0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 
  0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 
  0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 
  0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 
  0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 
  0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 
  0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 
  0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.6, 
  0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 
  0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 
  0.6, 0.6, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 
  0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 
  0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 
  0.8, 0.8, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 
  0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 
  1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 
  1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 
  1.4, 1.4, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.7, 1.7, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 1.9, 2, 
  2.1};

Show[Histogram[data, Automatic, "PDF"], 
 Plot[Tooltip[PDF[#, x], #], {x, 0, 2.1}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
    PlotStyle -> {Thick, Blue}] & /@ {WeibullDistribution[1.692103, 0.717062]}, 
 Plot[Tooltip[PDF[#, x], #], {x, 0, 2.1}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
    PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}] & /@ {WeibullDistribution[1.650914, 0.715745]}, 
 Plot[Tooltip[PDF[#, x], #], {x, 0, 2.1}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
    PlotStyle -> {Thick, Green}] & /@ {WeibullDistribution[1.667792, 0.716308]}, 
 Plot[Tooltip[PDF[#, x], #], {x, 0, 2.1}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
    PlotStyle -> {Thick, Orange}] & /@ {WeibullDistribution[1.860639, 0.713741]}, 
 Plot[Tooltip[PDF[#, x], #], {x, 0, 2.1}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
    PlotStyle -> {Thick, Gray}] & /@ {WeibullDistribution[1.72049, 0.72098]}, 
 Frame -> {True, True, False, False}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Wind speed (m/s)", "Probability density function "}, Axes -> False, 
 ImageSize -> 500, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

```
params =
  {{1.692103, 0.717062},
   {1.650914, 0.715745},
   {1.667792, 0.716308},
   {1.860639, 0.713741},
   {1.72049, 0.72098}};

colors = {Blue, Red, Green, Orange, Gray};

labels = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

Block[{x},
  Tooltip[PDF[WeibullDistribution @@ #, x], #] & /@ params //
     Plot[#, {x, 0, 2.1}, AspectRatio -> Automatic,
      PlotStyle   -> Thread[{Thick, colors}], 
      PlotLegends -> labels] &;
]

Show[Histogram[data, Automatic, "PDF"], %,
 Frame      -> {True, True, False, False},
 FrameLabel -> {"Wind speed (m/s)", "Probability density function "},
 Axes       -> False,
 ImageSize  -> 500,
 BaseStyle  -> {FontSize -> 14}
]
```

[image]